# Load AJAX in parent page, give access to variables in child pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I've got a parent page that houses a series of iframes. These all reside on the same domain.

I've got an AJAX call that runs within each iframe when it loads and it retrieves some JSON for me that I'm using to populate inputs that reside within it. It's the same information being retrieved by each iframe.

Currently, I'm running that AJAX call inside of each iframe. This doesn't strike me as particularly performant and I'm encountering issues with this. In some cases depending on the order the DOM loads, one iframe will have the correct data available while another won't have any at all.

My thought now (and open to suggestion) is to load the AJAX once within the parent page, store the data I need as local storage variables and then call those from within each iframe. Idea being it loads once (before the iframes are called) so that the data is there and defined, every time.

As a rough proof of concept I've got this;

**Parent page**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.urlofsite.com/mylookupfile.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  data: {Finder: finderID}, 
  success: finderAccess,
  error: finderDecline
});

function finderAccess(data) {
  console.log("sucessful send:");   
  
  // Parsing the returned data from the DB into a JSON object
  var useableData = $.parseJSON(data);
  console.log(useableData);

 // Set the session variables that will be used by each form 
  localStorage.setItem('fName', useableData.fname);
  const sessfName = localStorage.getItem('fName');  

  localStorage.setItem('lName', useableData.lname);
  const sesslName = localStorage.getItem('lName'); 

 }

 //error function and some other non-related scripts follow
```

So now I've got my session vars set and it works within the parent page. If I call something like

```
$(".class-name-of-a-p").html(sessfName);
```

The paragraph with that class properly displays the value stored in the variable.

Moving onto the iframe now...

**Iframe**

```
  $("#person_first_name").val(sessfName);
  $("#person_last_name").val(sesslName);
```

My understanding of the HTML Local Storage method of creating local storage variables is that they are available as long as the domain is the same. That's the case here, but, in the iframe the console tells me the variables don't exist and throws an error.

Comment: Your variables were declared in the scope of the function, so once the function in complete, those variables are destroyed. Create a variable with a global scope, set the data in the callback, then access it elsewhere.

Comment: Check the Application => Local Storage in the Inspector Tools on your site and verify if the localStorage variables get stored properly or not

Comment: @MattClark that makes sense! So then how would I get my data from the JSON success function to be accessible by a global function that would initiate these local storage vars? First go at this and any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly... The variable `sessfName` is declared in the parent page. Be it at global scope... Anyway it is in the parent page. The variables are not shared between frames. That is why you had the idea to use `localStorage` right? So read from localStorage in each iframe. `$("#person_first_name").val(localStorage.getItem('fName'))`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that sounded like an awesome idea, I've put it in practice but my input it still coming up empty. No console errors though at least.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette made some tweaks and your suggestion worked, thanks a million! And yes, your understanding of the questions is exactly right, which is why I went down the localStorage path.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 Using `localStorage` is a lot more complicated an approach than necessary for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Store the Ajax request in the `window` object (in your top-level frame):

```
window.lookup = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.urlofsite.com/mylookupfile.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  data: {Finder: finderID}, 
});
```

Now, in each of your child frames, you can do

```
window.parent.lookup.done(function (data) {
    // work with data
});
```

and all iFrames will receive the request as soon as it's there.

This works because `$.ajax` returns a promise. This promise is stored in `window.lookup`. You register as many `.done()` callbacks with a promise as you like - all of them will be notified when the promised result (the Ajax request in this case) is available. It also caches the data - frames that load later (or are created later) will receive the result immediately.

---

If you want to do some pre-processing before you hand down the data to your child frames, use `.then()` in the main top frame:

```
window.lookup = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.urlofsite.com/mylookupfile.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  data: {Finder: finderID}, 
}).then(function (data) {
  var modifiedData = doSomethingWith(data);
  return modifiedData;
});
```

Now all child frames will receive `modifiedData`.

Error handling can be done in the top frame (this error handler will be called once):

```
window.parent.lookup.done(function (data) {
    // work with data
}).fail();
  url: 'https://www.urlofsite.com/mylookupfile.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  data: {Finder: finderID}, 
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  finderDecline();
});
```

or in the child frame (this will be called once per frame):

```
window.parent.lookup.done(function (data) {
  // work with data
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // do something appropriate
});
```

or in both.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak ! Really appreciate the lengthy explanation of the steps and how this all works. I've just got a local storage based solution working and will keep it intact as a fallback option. I'll give this one a try now and see if I can get it working! As I said, really appreciate the thorough explanation and seeing another way to approach doing something.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 localStorage works, but it's another moving part. It's always best to try and reduce the number of moving parts in a solution. Also, since you refresh this data on page load, and do not intend to store it locally for the sake of ... you know, having it available offline/across page loads, it's a little bit of a misapplication of localStorage. It works, but it's not what it was intended to be used for.